# Python Logging - Closing one file across multiple logs (ResourceWarning)

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, file-io, python-logging

I created a custom `logging.Logger` that is used by several different objects in a script I'm running like so:

```
class TestLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name, file=None):
        super(TestLogger, self).__init__(name, level=logging.DEBUG)
        self.log_file = file
        ...

    def addLogFile(self, log_file):
        self.log_file = log_file
        self.setFormat()

    # set the format of the log
    def setFormat(self, default=True, end='\n'):

        # remove any Handlers
        self.removeStreamHandlers()
        self.removeFileHandlers()

        # get the log format string, default or message
        format_str = DEFAULT_FORMAT if default else CUSTOM_FORMAT

        std_formatter = logging.Formatter(format_str, datefmt=self.DATE_FORMAT)

        # add the stream handler
        console = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        console.setFormatter(std_formatter)
        console.terminator = end
        self.addHandler(console)

        # add the file handler
        if self.log_file:
            file_formatter = logging.Formatter(format_str, datefmt=self.DATE_FORMAT)
            logger = logging.FileHandler(self.log_file)
            logger.setFormatter(file_formatter)
            self.addHandler(logger)

    # remove all stream handlers
    def removeStreamHandlers(self):
        stream_handlers = [h for h in self.handlers if isinstance(h, logging.StreamHandler)
                           and not isinstance(h, logging.FileHandler)]
        for sh in stream_handlers:
            self.removeHandler(sh)

    # remove all file handlers
    def removeFileHandlers(self):
        file_handlers = [h for h in self.handlers if isinstance(h, logging.StreamHandler)
                         and isinstance(h, logging.FileHandler)]
        for fh in file_handlers:
            self.removeHandler(fh)

class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = TestLogger('Something')
        ...
    def __del__(self):
        self.log.removeFileHandlers()
        self.log.removeStreamHandler()

class SomethingElse:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = TestLogger('SomethingElse')
        ...
    def __del__(self):
        self.log.removeFileHandlers()
        self.log.removeStreamHandler()
```

All of these objects are initialized and designed to share the same log file like so:

```
log_file = 'test.log'
s = Something()
se = SomethingElse()
s.addLogFile(log_file)
se.addLogFile(log_file)
...
del s, se
```

The problem seems to be that when I try to rerun my program, it throws a `ResourceWarning` every time I run `setFormat()`. It seems like the file isn't properly being closed and I'm not sure where this could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should reuse the handlers. If you want to change the formatter just call `setFormatter` on the existing handlers and keep them.

If you really do want to throw away the handler and use a new one, there is a `close()` method on the FileHandler that is supposed to be called to clean up when the handler is done logging. So in your case you would change your code to look like this:

```
        for fh in file_handlers:
            fh.close()
            self.removeHandler(fh)
```